# How to fix an incorrect collision of objects in unity3d when using Rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Objects of the same mass, shape, one should crash into the other with the required speed, but in a collision it is clear that it passes a little and returns, or passes and gets stuck in it. How do I make the object stop when it collides?

`

```
[SerializeField] KeyCode keyOne;
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyTwo;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 moveDirection;




    // Update is called once per frame
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(keyOne)) 
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(keyTwo)) 
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity -= moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ResetLevel();
        }
    }
```

`

I tried using velocity and addforce, it didn't help... I also tried to change the rigidbody settings, also unsuccessfully.

Comment: Consider storing the result of the call to `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` in a _member field_ rather than so possibly **60 times a second**. :O

Comment: Also, you **should not** modify the velocity of an object with a rigid body as it defeats the purpose.  Just use forces and torque.  You were on the right track initially. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `rigidbody.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous`